# Publish app to App Store with Stripe

Tags: ios, app-store, stripe-payments

What is the common workflow of publishing app with Stripe. 
At development stage I can use test stripe keys for testing.
But before submitting to App Store I have to change public key to production.
And my question is: what information I should provide to Apple? How they can test payment process with production Stripe?

Comment: I've never used Stripe but I would think that Stripe documents this. No?

Comment: The problem isn't connected to Stripe. They have test mode. But I can't publish the app in test mode. The problem is - I'm publishing the app with production keys when Apple have to test the payment somehow

Comment: I'd recommend two things here (1) when you submit your app you have space give apple details such as a testing account to use, (2) rather than hard coding your publishable key in your app, you could pull it dynamically from your server. If you do this, an added benefit, if you need to roll your key some time in the future you can swap it in without submitting a new version of your app for approval.

Comment: @duck Doesn't seem like the safest move to dynamically pull secret keys from a server. How do you verify it's an authorized request and not someone trying to steal your keys? Plus what if your server were to go down for whatever reason? Just seems like one more thing you have to maintain, keep alive, and secure. But the security thing seems like the biggest problem.

Comment: An iOS app for Stripe, like Checkout or Stripe.js, never uses a Secret Key, only the Publishable Key for tokenization (in web based scenarios this key is presented in the page source itself, its not especially sensitive). The actual charge request, and the Secret Key acts only on the server itself and should never be in the app in any way.

Comment: @RomanVolkov did you find the best way to go here?