# How can I let App Store Reviewers test the App with Stripe?

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, stripe-payments, appstore-approval

Our App has Stripe Connect integrated as the payment gateway.

How can I let reviewers test the payment functionality, when Stripe is in live mode? What is the best use case here?

(Ideally, I'd provide two demo accounts with two different roles: buyer and seller, which means two stripe accounts are required

Possible Solutions I have thought about:

- Store live and test keys in database, and allow the reviewer to test payments with test cards/accounts. If App is accepted, updating the keys manually in the backend to comply.
- Advising them to not test payments at all, unless they don't have a demo stripe account themselves.

Would be great to receive any help/advice!

P.S.: other similar questions (I could find) have not been answered in this regard, not well enough, eg: [Publish app to App Store with Stripe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540270/publish-app-to-app-store-with-stripe)

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach here is to keep your API Keys in *your* database and then allow them to retrieve a key for live or test mode from within the App.  This is usually the best approach anyway.  If they're a connected account already and you know their account id, you can use the `Stripe-Account`-header and your platform's API Keys to do basically anything.

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#stripe-account-header